# Gitiginore all files except those with .rst extensions?

Tags: git, gitignore

The ** and * in gitignore are a bit confusing. Here is what I have in .gitignore:

```
*
!*.rst
```

This works for all *.rst files in the root directory. What about .rst files in subdirectories?

I tried

```
*
!*.rst
!**/*.rst
```

But this does not change anything.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following in your .gitignore

```
*
!*.rst
!*/
```

This way you tell git to not ignore subdirectories.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem (with a different extension) and putting this in my .gitignore file, just ignores everything

Answer (score 0):

If you read this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681262/difference-in-the-paths-in-gitignore-file/681280#681280), you will realize the way Git ignore files is system-dependent.

> the [`gitignore` manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) clearly says that the glob will be passed un-altered to the system's `fnmatch` library function

So what OS and Git distro are you using (Unix, or Msysgit on Windows)?
Because on Windows, the '`**`' does not work very well (if at all).

Plus, make sure your *.rst files were not already added to the cache before you declared them in the .gitignore file. They would need to be removed from the cache (and the purged cache committed) before .gitignore works as intended (see also this [blog post](http://constantinz.wordpress.com/2009/08/20/git-gitignore-file-missunderstanding/))