# .gitignore slash after wildcard changes exclude behaviour

Tags: git, gitignore

If the .gitignore file looks like this:

```
*
!adir/
```

then the directory adir will not be included. However, if I change it to:

```
*/
!adir/
```

Now it works - all directories are ignored but adir. Why is that? What is the proper way of ignoring everything but some particular directories?

**EDIT:**
Based on the answer, I changed it to:

```
*
!adir/
!adir/*
```

and it works. But is there any preferred way?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241644/using-gitignore-to-ignore-everything-but-specific-directories for some good ideas.

Comment: Please don't add your tag (e.g. git) at the front of your question (and please use a more descriptive title next time). This time, I edited that in for you. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you wrote `*`, git understood "ignore every files".

Git doesn't version folders, only files, so it saw `adir/` as an empty directory.