# how to ignore all file and directory except a directory I need by using .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

When I pushed my project to github I needed a problem.The structure of my project like this: [image]

Now I want to upload `.gitignore` `README.md` and all of directory `d2`.

I don't want to write directory in `.gitignore` because the project not only has `d1` I don't want to upload.There so many directory(d3,d4,d5) I don't want to upload.

I want to find a way  that I can ignore all the directory except `d2`.

I have tried to write `.gitignore` like this:

`*
!/d2/
!.gitignore
!./README.md`

But it didn't work.

Do anyone know how to do?Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241644/using-gitignore-to-ignore-everything-but-specific-directories) ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following `.gitignore`.

```
/*
!/d2/
!.gitignore
!README.md
```

`*` ignores all files in directories in all depth, while `/*` only ignores the files and directories under the root level.

By the way, if you want that it still works with `*`, you need to add `!/d2/**` as follows.

```
*
!/d2/
!/d2/**
!.gitignore
!README.md
```