# Why GIT is not tracking new files of a directory?

Tags: git, gitignore

I want git to track changes to a specific folder named `BananaProject.Widget.Controls`. The folder lies at the root directory of the project, just as `.gitignore`.

I am trying to ignore anything else except the activity on that folder but **GIT** **does** **not track a new file** created inside that directory. On the contrary, it tracks changes to files that already exist.

Here is the `.gitignore`

```
*
!/BananaProject.Widget.Controls/*
```

What am I doing wrong?

### Edit

Because I want to create C# files I also tried this without any success

```
*
!/BananaProject.Widget.Controls/*.cs
```

Comment: * is a wildcard so i am thinking, if you have it the way it is in your code snippet, then you may be telling git to ignore all files in the directory.

Comment: That's true @AfiaUdofia but the `!` negates the pattern. So the first line means ignore everything and the second line means except that pattern.

Comment: shouldn't they be on the same line?

Comment: I believe every pattern should be in its own line.

Comment: Does this answer the question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241644/using-gitignore-to-ignore-everything-but-specific-directories  or this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248570/how-do-i-tell-git-to-ignore-everything-except-a-subdirectory

Comment: Unfortunately no @Amy, shouldn't this be a simple task?

Comment: It is a simple task, yes.

Comment: Try removing the leading `/`.  That's rooting the path to your drive root, not the project root.

Comment: Doesn't work either. @Amy

Comment: Git doesn't track new files; you have to `git add` them.

Comment: If you're on a system that's case-insensitive, does your directory name match the case exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I tell Git to ignore everything except a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248570/how-do-i-tell-git-to-ignore-everything-except-a-subdirectory)

Comment: what does `git status --ignored` say?

Comment: Just in case, even if the files are being ignored (and you can't figure out why), you can still force git to track them by using -f on `git add`.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me, with Git version 2.17.1

Directory tree:

```
/tmp
*--- git/
    *--- .gitignore
    *--- foo/
        *--- bar
```

Contents of .gitignore:

```
./*
!foo/
```

Output of `git status`:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .gitignore
    foo/
```

I can then add `foo/` and it tracks the file `bar`.

Comment: Ah, but OP maybe wants it to track `bar` without doing `git add foo`.