# How to exclude folder .gitignore

Tags: git, directory, gitignore

How can i exclude everything but only specific directory to publish git by using .gitignore

### For example my root tree

```
-node_modules
-js
-ts
-releases 
-package.json
```

I want to only add releases folder and all contents to my git branch.

#### What I tried

```
*
!releases
```

```
*
!releases/
```

Comment: This question should probably be reformatted to ask how to exclude everything by default and only include specific files and directories using `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to ignore everything by default but whitelist certain directories. If so you may find this post helpful:

https://jasonstitt.com/gitignore-whitelisting-patterns

For your scenario you may want to try adding a double wildcard (to allow traversal below that folder) at the end of the folder you want to include like this:

```
*
!folder_name/**
```

Comment: it works. only add `!*/` after '*" . Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

just mention the folder name in `.gitignore` like this:

```
folder_name
```

if this is not in the same directory, you can do this:

```
path/to/the/sub_folder
```

Comment: i want to exclude it if do in that way it will be included. I will edit my question to be more clear

Comment: Check this out:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241644/using-gitignore-to-ignore-everything-but-specific-directories)