# what does tmp/**/* ignore in .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

In my .gitignore file I have

```
tmp/**/*
```

What files does it exclude? Will it exclude all tmp and files/folders under it?

My other question is, is this different from the following?

```
tmp/*
```

Edit:

Reason I ask is because I a have this

```
.vimbackup/**/*
```

but it is NOT ignoring a file like `.vimbackup/.somebackup~`

However, if I do

```
.vimbackup/*
```

it DOES ignore the file `.vimbackup/.somebackup~`  Seems kinda backwards to me

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681262/difference-in-the-paths-in-gitignore-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually that notation means to include any subdirectory within tmp. And then files within those directories too (because of the additional `/*`)

It includes sub-directories recursively as well. So `tmp/billy/bob/*` will be ignored as well as `tmp/banjo/*` and so on...

That being said. I've never used git... so I could be wrong. But many IDEs and version control programs use that notation.

Just noticed your second question. Yes it is different from just `tmp/*` Which will ignore all files, but not directories and their respective files.

Answer (score 1):

If a file has already been committed then git will remember it until you explicitly get git to remove it from the index/staging area. This is even if you update the .gitignore file, which can be confusing.

look at `git rm <file>` for removing a file that has been previously committed that you are now ignoring via the .gitignore file (see many SO Q&As).