# My .gitignore file is matching items that I did not expect it to match?

Tags: gitignore

I have a .gitignore file with the following:

cache/

resources/

The file correctly matches the directories in my root:

cache/

resources/

The files in these directories are ignored and therefore because this is a git system, the directories themselves are ignored. This is also good.

But it also matches a sub directory in a sibling root directory:

default/cms/resources/library/index.cfm

And ignores this path which is not good.

How can I rewrite the .gitignore file so that:

default/cms/resources/library/index.cfm

Is not matched?

And only files & subdirectories inside cache/ & resources/ are matched.

Thank you in advance for any advice you can give me.

Comment: This is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files

Comment: @alvits Thanks for the link but it does not address this specific issue. The link you have given me, imparts general advice about .gitignore patterns.

Comment: @alvits For instance would placing a leading forward slash to the examples solve the issue:

Comment: @alvits Like: /cache/ or /resources/

Comment: Placing a `!` before a pattern is what you need. For example you can add `!default/cms/resources` in your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: @alvits Thanks for your advice, but surely there is a cleaner solution. Can you tell me why my example is matching that path in the first place?

Comment: @alvits Are you telling me I have to trawl through every path in my root excluding everything with 'resources' or 'cache' as a sub directory. That cannot be right?

Comment: @alvits Can you tell me what: resources/** does?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested, I have done some in depth tests using .gitignore [which I probably should have done in the first place, but I guess I was just being lazy], and the answer to the question is:

cache/**

resources/**

I hope this helps anyone, in a similar situation...

Comment: I honestly have not used `**` which is supposed to be a recursive version of `*`. According [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681262/difference-in-the-paths-in-gitignore-file) it is system dependent. [This doc](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) says that `resources/**` will exclude everything from the directory `resources` relative to the location of `.gitignore`. You just solved your own post. Cheers :)

Comment: @alvits It seems to be both recursive to its direct descendants & recursive in sibling directories. In fact, it seems to cover everything!

Comment: @alvits "Excludes everything relative to .gitignore..." Now, this makes sense, in relation to why it covers sibling directories. Thanks for the explanation.